Surface scratch on carbon steerer
Following my previous post, I managed to find an identical new fork replacement from a reseller since the communication with the company was absolutely terrible...
When I unpacked the fork though, I noticed a super obvious scratch on the steerer which seems however just on the surface level of the steerer. I really cannot detect any exposure of the carbon fibers anywhere along the scratch. It seems though that the fork was scratched after production when moved/stored or something.

I've let the reseller know about that, and I'll have my bike shop check that next week.
The question is if this seems like something that I should worry about again...
